# Quick question: If G is a p-group, then G is its own sylow p group.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Suppose I have a p-group G. Is G equal to its own sylow p group (in this case there is only one sylow p group)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: if $G$ is a finite group of order $n=p^km$ with $k>0$ and $(m,p)=1$, then a Sylow $p$-subgroup is a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^k$. In particular, if $m=1$ then the only Sylow $p$-subgroup is $G$ itself.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know whether trivial subgroups were allowed.

Comment: Trivial subgroups can be Sylow subgroups. For any prime $q$ that does not divide $|G|$, the Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$ is trivial.